# What's the difference between ".yy & .xx {...} " and ".yy .xx {...} " in stylus?

Tags: stylus

What's the difference between "A" and "B " in stylus ?

```
A:
.yy 
    & .xx 
        {...}
--------
B:
.yy 
    .xx 
        {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In A, the use of the `&` signals that the two classes apply to the same element. That is, you'll match an element like this:

```
<div class="yy xx">...</div>
```

In B, the two selectors are nested. So you'll match any `class='xx'` inside a `class='yy'`.

```
<div class="xx">I don't match</div>
<div class="yy">
  <div class="xx">I match</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same expressions.example A  is redundant. By default, there are nesting in Stylus. So you can always use the example B